# Why does this proof show the gluon propagator comes from the first two terms?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, propagator, gluons

I am reading the book "QCD: Renormalization for the Practitioner" and i am having trouble understanding something. In page 70 the gluon propagator is written as follows

$$\begin{multline}
iD^{\mu\nu}(k)=iD^{(0)\mu\nu}(k)+iD^{(0)\mu\lambda}(k)\bigl[i\Pi_{\lambda\rho}(k)\bigr]iD^{(0)\rho\nu}(k) \\
+iD^{(0)\mu\lambda}(k)\bigl[i\Pi_{\lambda\rho}(k)\bigr]iD^{(0)\rho\tau}(k)\bigl[i\Pi_{\tau\sigma}(k)\bigr]iD^{(0)\sigma\nu}(k)+\ldots
\end{multline}$$

A $k_{\mu}$ is introduced in this equation giving

$$\begin{multline}
ik_{\mu}D^{\mu\nu}(k)=ik_{\mu}D^{(0)\mu\nu}(k)+ik_{\mu}D^{(0)\mu\lambda}(k)\bigl[i\Pi_{\lambda\rho}(k)\bigr]iD^{(0)\rho\nu}(k) \\
+ik_{\mu}D^{(0)\mu\lambda}(k)\bigl[i\Pi_{\lambda\rho}(k)\bigr]iD^{(0)\rho\tau}(k)\bigl[i\Pi_{\tau\sigma}(k)\bigr]iD^{(0)\sigma\nu}(k)+\ldots
\end{multline}$$

Then the [Slavnov identity](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Slavnov-Taylor_identities) $k_{\mu}D^{\mu\nu}_{bc}(k)=-a\delta_{ab}\frac{1}{k^2}k^{\nu}$ is summoned, where $a$ is the gauge fixing parameter, and it is claimed that as a consequence we have

$$ik_{\mu}D^{(0)\mu\lambda}(k)\bigl[i\Pi_{\lambda\rho}(k)\bigr]\Bigl(iD^{(0)\rho\nu}(k)+iD^{(0)\rho\tau}(k)\bigl[i\Pi_{\tau\sigma}(k)\bigr]iD^{(0)\sigma\nu}(k)+\ldots\Bigr)=0$$

How does this follow?

Moreover, in the next line it is claimed that a consequence of all this is

$$-a\frac{1}{k^2+i\eta}k^{\lambda}i\Pi_{\lambda\rho}(k)iD^{\rho\nu}(k)=0$$

How does this too follow?

A consequence of all this is that the only contribution to the gluon propagator comes from only the first two terms in the first expansion but I don't see the whole picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you left out some bits and pieces here and there. Applying the Slavnov identity (which, I assume, also goes for the bare propagator $D^{(0)}$), one can cancel the left-hand side with the first term of the right-hand side (both being $-ia\delta_{ab}\frac1{k^2}k^\nu$). Then you bring some factors to the front to find that your third (indented) expression is equal to zero.

Your last equation follows by recognizing $iD^{\mu\nu}(k)$ between the brackets in the previous line, and applying the Slavnov identity to $D^{(0)}$ (with an infinitesimal $\eta$ added to stay away from the pole).

Comment: you have answered everything but one thing. Maybe you could also tell me how all this implies that the full gluon propagator is only the sum of the first two terms in the first equation I have written

Comment: Hm, I don't think that follows, really. Do you have any reason why it should?

Comment: it is written at page 71 of the book I have mentioned http://www.amazon.es/Qcd-Renormalization-Practitioner-Lecture-Physics/dp/3540129081

Comment: maybe you would like to help me with http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/182332/problem-in-the-derivation-of-the-ward-identities